# ESLint with Arbnb config and Facebook Flow together

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, eslint, flowtype

I am using ESLint in a project and want to use Facebook flow as well, But I am getting warnings from ESLint on flow type annotations.

I have .flowconfig and .eslintrc in project root.

.eslintrc:

```javascript
// When you write javascript you should follow these soft rules and best practices
// https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

// This is a link to best practices and enforcer settings for eslint
// https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb

// Use this file as a starting point for your project's .eslintrc.
{
  "extends": "airbnb",

  "plugins": [
    "flow-vars"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "flow-vars/define-flow-type": 1,
    "flow-vars/use-flow-type": 1
  }
}
```

What should I do to make it work? Is there a way to run flow in watch task together using webpack?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**[`flow-vars`](https://github.com/zertosh/eslint-plugin-flow-vars) is deprecated!**

This is the current proper way of getting Flow running with Airbnb's (with [`eslint-plugin-flowtype`](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype)):

*This assumes you already have [flow](https://github.com/facebook/flow) installed.*

```
npm install --save-dev eslint babel-eslint eslint-plugin-flowtype
```

.eslintrc

```
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:flowtype/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": [
    "flowtype"
  ]
}
```

Want [custom configuration](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype#configuration) instead?

Answer (score 8):

For me, the problem was solved by adding `"parser": "babel-eslint"` to my `.eslintrc`.

(I had to run `npm install babel-eslint --save-dev` first though).

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "parser": "babel-eslint", // <--
  "plugins": [
    "flow-vars"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "flow-vars/define-flow-type": 1,
    "flow-vars/use-flow-type": 1
  }
}
```